# Chance Color of MRTK3 Icons on CompressableButtons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

Soo I use the Prefab of the NearMenue to Display a bar of 4 Buttons that follow me. I now want to color them depending on what's happening.

So far I get the right TextMeshPro from UX.Button.Icon.Char and set the color there and this works. Well unless I actually look at the Button, then the Color gets changed back to white.

Anyone knows a way to stop this?

Comment: Look, meaning hover mouse over it? If so, you probably have got default transition settings on your button.

Comment: @bartol44 Happens with Mouse, Finger and Gaze Hover. Animations and such are of course on I just could not find the point where the color gets set on the component. I saw somwhere that MRTK2 had Themes where I need to set the color but I have no Idea where/ how I can find that and if that even still counts for MRTK3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So under the "State Visualizer" Sript there is a Vissual State called "Disabled".
For whatever reason the Disabled State gets triggered once I look at the button and it will run the "Graphic Tint" effect that goes through the Tintables from Top to Bottom and colors everything depending on the Color of th Top Object and ignores every color setting you did below or in the graphic tint effect itself.
Because I only colored the Icon and not the Text and the Default List says Text then Icon my Icon always got changed back to white. Once I removed the Effect/ the Text from the Tintable List everything works fine.